# How to check for duplicate letter in a array of strings. python

Tags: python, list

So if I have a list

```
word = ['cat','laap','cabb']
```

How can I check if the adjacent letter is a duplicate? I was thinking that with i position I can go to the first index of the array and with j to check every individual letter? Is this the right approach?

Note: that my tabs might be wrong in my code I find stack over tag code to be a little weird.

```
words = ['cat','laap','cabb']
for i in range(len(words)): 
    for j in range(len(words)):
        if(words[i][j]==word[i][j+1]):
            print('dup')
```

Comment: You're asking about letter duplicates, but your algorithm checks for words, so I'm a little confused on what you actually want.

Comment: Your approach is right. But please post such questions [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: So I'm trying to check the duplicate letter within the words. I changed the second for loop to this for j in range(len(words[i])): to account for the length of the word so I can loop over the letter to check for duplicates

Comment: It may print multiple times same word if it has multiple repeating characters, may be you can use continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you wanted to write is more like

```
words = ['cat','laap','cabb']

for word in words:
    for index, character in enumerate(word):
        if word[index + 1] == character:
            print('dup')
```

But beware, this fails at the last letter (even your code does). To avoid this, you can write

```
for word in words:
    for index, character in enumerate(word[:-1]):
        if word[index + 1] == character:
            print('dup')
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can also try using `zip` with `set comprehension` :

```
results = {w for w in word for ch1, ch2 in zip(w, w[1:]) if ch1 == ch2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip(word, word[1:])` to create 2 element tuples of consecutive letters in a word, convert the tuple to set and check if its length is 1 to check if both the elements are same, and use `any` to check that for any letter pair

```
>>> words = ['cat','laap','cabb']
>>> any(any(len(set(t))==1 for t in zip(w, w[1:])) for w in words)
True
```